# Celery periodic tasks once in 2 weeks

Tags: python, django, celery, periodic-task

I am having trouble setting a periodic task with Celery to run once in 2 weeks on Sunday nights. Does anyone have any idea how to configure that with `day_of_month` `day_of_week` options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to my knowledge, this couldn't be done solely with `crontab`

first, make your task run on every Sunday night:

```
crontab(minute=0, hour=0, day_of_week='sunday')
```

then, in your task function, check if the week number is even, if so, do nothing:

```
from datetime import datetime

week_number = int(datetime.today().strftime("%U"))    
if week_number % 2 == 0:
    return
```

Comment: Still one question, what could be the reason of the task getting executed multiple times?? I set it down to the minute but it keeps getting executed hundreds of times

Comment: @Ken I am afraid I have to take a look at your setting.

Comment: `
CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
`

Comment: @Ken I mean your periodic task setting :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob here. I can't get the comment correctly formatted. The configuration of the task is attached to the definition of the task. Here

@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute=19, hour=11, day_of_week='friday')),
    name='Расчет отчета партнеров',
    # ignore_result=True
)

Comment: @Ken as `@periodic_task` has been removed long time ago, no help I could offer to here.

Comment: I didn't know about that. I used it in my project from some months ago and it works perfectly. So what is the new way of doing it? I'm just so frustrated because even the timezone settings are not working. It just uses UTC no matter the setting

Comment: @Ken first you need a newer version of celery, then check the [document](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules)

Comment: I have the latest version 4.1.0. I've tried reading the docs too but didn't help. They recommended using the django-celery-beat and setting up the schedule in the seetings file. I have tried that like this.
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    '2 weeks': {
        'task': 'cbf.partners.tasks.make_invoice',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=37, hour=11, day_of_week='friday'),
    }
}
It doesn't even detect it

Comment: @georgexsh Why not do `crontab(minute=0, hour=0, day_of_month='1, 14')`?

Comment: @theTypan OP wants to run on Sunday.

Comment: @georgexsh My bad...missed that in the question description